# postgresql pslq selecting variables from table in for loop

Tags: postgresql, variables, plpgsql

Trying to use variable tn as tablename is select query

I have tried putting variable name tn in || tn || syntax
I have tried putting variable name tn in :tn syntac

```
do $$
    declare tn varchar ;
    begin
        for tn in select tablename from gil_reb_tabn_list
        loop
            EXECUTE 'select count (*) from tn';
        end loop;
    end;
$$;
```

The error is:

> ```
> psql:readme_mas_list.sql:9: ERROR:  relation "tn" does not exist
> LINE 1: select count (*) from tn
>                               ^
> QUERY:  select count (*) from tn
> CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 6 at EXECUTE
> ```

I would expect to use tn as a tablename variable to loop over the select query.

Answer (score 0):

You could rewrite it as:

```
do $$
    declare tn varchar ;
    begin
        for tn in select tablename from gil_reb_tabn_list
        loop
            EXECUTE FORMAT('select count (*) from %I', tn);
        end loop;
    end;
$$;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=e1fbe3d09ce99da6f69aab3d33becb34)**